# unknown file in ~/.cache/wallpaper

Tags: files, 16.10, desktop-background, cache

In my `~/.cache/wallpaper` directory there is a file:

> 0_5_1600_1200_792beab7550410d531e55f95b449f135

What is this?  Should/can I delete it?

Comment: What happens when you try to open that file? What's the output of `file ~/.cache/wallpaper/0_5_1600_1200_792beab7550410d531e55f95b449f135`?

Answer (score 3):

It's the picture you are using as your desktop background, scaled to your 1600x1200 px. If you delete it it will be recreated the next time you log in or change your desktop background.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, most files in cache or .cache folders can be deleted as these files are temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

I have two similar cache files on my system:

```
~$ l ~/.cache/wallpaper
0_5_1920_1080_68dd513142fc5b210b72f532465b3450
1_5_1920_1080_68dd513142fc5b210b72f532465b3450
```

Using Nautilus I can see they are two images from the regular wallpaper that cycles every 30 minutes or so on my screen. They are not the currently mounted wallpaper image on my desktop though. As they are copies of images displayed a few hours ago, I simply deleted them with no ill-effect.